# How to create a public unix domain socket?

Tags: unix-sockets, nc

Consider `/var/run/acpid.socket`. At any point I can connect to it and disconnect from it. Compare that with `nc`:

```
$ nc -l -U ./myunixsocket.sock
Ncat: bind to ./myunixsocket.sock: Address already in use. QUITTING.
```

`nc` apparently allows only single-use sockets. Question is then, how do I create a socket analogous to `/var/run/acpid.socket`, for multiple use and reuse ?

Comment: The two cases are not equivalent.  With `nc` you are trying to have a "server" listening on the socket while something else is already listening to it. In the first case, a single `acpid` instance is listening on the socket.  In both cases, multiple clients can write to it. (All this written with an appropriate amount of handwaving).

Comment: It's not true that `nc` allows only single-use sockets. What's true, is that `nc` is not a real server (it will not `fork` a subprocess to handle a connection, then go back to accepting connections while the child is still running, like eg. the X11 server or `acpid` do); while `nc -l` is handling a connection, it will not `accept()` other connections on the same socket. And this is no different from how `nc -l` works with `tcp` sockets.

Comment: @Kusalananda So what do I do to make it equivalent ? I have to keep an extra listening `nc` process just to  allow multiple other listeners ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it with the `-k` option to `nc`.

> ```
> -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its cur-
>          rent connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option
>          without the -l option.  When used together with the -u option,
>          the server socket is not connected and it can receive UDP data-
>          grams from multiple hosts.
> ```

Example:

```
$ rm -f /tmp/socket    # unlink the socket if it already exists
$ nc -vklU /tmp/socket # the server
Connection from mack  received!
yes
Connection from mack  received!
yes
...
```

It's recommended to `unlink()` the socket after use -- but, in fact, most programs check if it exists and remove it **before** calling `bind()` on it; if the socket path exists in the filesystem and you try to `bind()` to it, you will get an `EADDRINUSE` error even when no program is using it in any way.

One way to avoid this whole mess on linux is to use ["abstract"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206386/what-does-the-symbol-denote-in-the-beginning-of-a-unix-domain-socket-path-in-l/206395) unix sockets, but they don't seem to be supported by `netcat`.